# How to get the workflow task title in a calculated field in workflow tasks list?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column-formula

I want to get the task title in a calcualted field to form a URL to custom approval page. Basically I tried

```
 =CONCATENATE("<a href=http://****/SitePages/ApprovalPage.aspx?WFTitle=",[Request Description],"'>Approve/Reject</a>")
```

But in [Request Description] value, I am getting part of the title value.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the spaces in the task title and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your formula, only one closing single quote but no opening single quote, so the browser adds quotes when it finds a space in your [Request Description] title; that's why you only get the first word.

You don't need the concatenate function, & concatenates as well

To prevent mixup with single quotes next to double quotes I tend to use the SharePoint escape notation of "" so a single HTML *double quote* is added in the SP string

Line breaks will be removed by SharePoint when the Formula is saved; it makes the Formula better readable; you can copy/paste this

```
 ="<a href=http://****/SitePages/ApprovalPage.aspx?WFTitle="""
 &[Request Description]
 &""">Approve/Reject</a>"
```